# defining a minimal bounding circle in matlab

Tags: matlab

The question is

> a.write a function which finds the circle with the minimal area s.t it bounds a given list of points (use fminsearch and give appropriate plot).
>   b.If you managed do the same for sphere (find one with minimal volume)

What I've tried so far:

```
%%Main function    
function minarea= mincircle(points)
maxx=max(points(1,:));
maxy=max(points(2m:));
radius=max(maxx,maxy);
minarea=fminsearch(@(x) circle(x,r,c),[0,0])
end
%%This function is supposed to give equalation of circle
function eq=circle(x,r,c)
eq=(x(1)-c(1)).^2+(x(2)-c(2)).^2 %=r?
% and here I don't know how to insert r:
end`
```

For better understanding I'll attach a sketch.

[image: a circle]

In these terms I want to find the area of the circle whose center is in O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** I don't believe that the circle you drew is the smallest possible bounding circle.  It should be a little smaller, up and to the right, and should touch at least two points on its perimeter.

### Approaching the problem

We have a set of points, and we want to draw a circle that encompasses all of them.  The problem is that you need three bits of information to define a circle: the X and Y coordinates of the circle's center, and the circle's radius.  So the problem doesn't seem straightforward.

However, there is a related problem that is much easier to solve.  Suppose the circle's center is fixed.  From that point, we make a circle grow concentrically outwards so that it becomes bigger and bigger.  At some point, the circle will encompass one of the points in our set.  As it gets bigger, it will encompass a second point, and a third, until all the points in our set fall within our circle.  Clearly, as soon as the last point in the set falls within our circle, we have the smallest possible circle that encompasses all the points, given that we started by fixing the center point of the circle.

Moreover, we can determine what the radius of this circle is.  It is simply the maximum distance from any point in the set to the center of the circle, since we stop when the last point is touched by the perimeter of our expanding circle.

The next problem is to determine *What is the best starting point to place the center of our circle?*  Clearly if the starting point is far away from all the points in our set, then the radius must be very large to even encompass one point in the set.  Intuitively, it must be "in the middle" of our points somewhere.  But where, exactly?

### Using `fminsearch`

My suggestion is that you want to find the point P(x, y) that minimises how large you have to grow the circle to encompass all the points in the set.  And we're in luck that we can use `fminsearch` to find P.

[According to the `fminsearch` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html), the function you pass in must be a function of one parameter (which may be an array), and it must return a scalar.  The idea is that you want the output of your function to be as small as possible, and you want to find out what inputs will make that possible.

In our case, we want to write a function that outputs the *size* of our circle, given the *center* of the circle as input.  That way, `fminsearch` will find the center of the smallest possible circle that will still encompass all the points.  I'm going to write a function that outputs the radius required to encompass all the points given a center point P.

```
pointsX = [..]; % X-coordinates of points in the set
pointsY = [..]; % Y-coordinates of points in the set

function r = radiusFromPoint(P)
    px = P(1);
    py = P(2);
    distanceSquared = (pointsX - px).^2 + (pointsY - py).^2;
    r = sqrt(max(distanceSquared));
end
```

Then we want to use `fminsearch` to find the point that gives us the smallest radius.  I've just naively used the origin (0, 0) as my starting estimate, but you may have a better idea (like using the first point in the set)

```
P0 = [0, 0];  % starting estimate
[P, radiusMin] = fminsearch(@radiusFromPoint, P0);
```

The circle is defined by its center at `P` and radius of `radiusMin`.

And I'll leave it to you to plot the output and generalize to the 3D case!

Comment: I believe there is an error in your code. By minimizing the _minimum_ distance squared, your point `P` is going to gravitate towards the nearest input point, at which point `radiusMin == 0` (or close to it). You need to minimize the _maximum_ distance squared. At which point, all points will be contained in the circle, but the distance from the center point to the outermost point will be minimized. Also, since the OP's homework is long since overdue, I'd suggest that a good starting point for the initial guess is `P0=[median(X), median(Y)];`

Comment: Also, your approach has a distinct advantage over @user85109's approach because it allows for distance metrics other than Euclidean.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, while you may need it to complete your homework assignment (I assume that is what this is) you don't really need to use an optimizer at all. The minboundcircle code posted with my [minimal bounding tools](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34767-a-suite-of-minimal-bounding-objects) does it without use of an optimizer. (There is also a minboundsphere tool.)

Regardless, you might find a few tricks in there that will be useful. At the very least, learn how to reduce the size of the problem (and so the speed of solution) by use of a convex hull. After all, it is only the points on the convex hull that can determine a minimal bounding circle. All other points are simply a waste of CPU time.